# Retrive data from Mysql android php

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I want to retriev data from mysql data base according to an id send by the user in Editext and the result show it in listview
    this is my script php

```
<?php
$DB_USER='root'; 
$DB_PASS=''; 
$DB_HOST='localhost';
$DB_NAME='pfe';

$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}       

$comm = $_GET['comm'];
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$sql="SELECT nomco FROM commune where idwi=".$comm;
$result=$mysqli->query($sql);

while($e=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $output[]=$e; 
}   

print(json_encode($output)); 
$mysqli->close();   

?>
```

java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements      AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
   EditText idtxt;
   TextView txtaffich;

    ArrayAdapter<String> listadapter;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> listcom = new ArrayList<>();
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    idtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);


    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listadapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listcom);
    listView.setAdapter(listadapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

public void send(View view) {
    String id = idtxt.getText().toString();
    if (id.length() == 0 ) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Vous devez remplir les champs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "wait...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new SignupActivity().execute(id);

    Toast.makeText(this, id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}

public class SignupActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    ArrayList<String> me;


    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        me =new ArrayList<>();//pour lis

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        String idenv = arg0[0];
        InputStream is=null;

        String link;
        String data;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader2;
        String result="";

        try {//le message a envoyer + mail
            //we append to this URL a ‘?’ mark and the variable values
            // separated by ‘&’ sign, these values will be passed to the server by HTTP GET method.
            data = "?comm=" + URLEncoder.encode(idenv, "UTF-8");

            link = "http://192.168.43.93/pfe/select_spinner_com.php" + data;

            URL url = new URL(link);

            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            is= con.getInputStream();

            bufferedReader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            String line2 = "";
            while ((line2 = bufferedReader2.readLine().toString()) != null) {
                result += line2;


          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        try {

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int ii = 0; ii < jsonArray.length(); ii++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(ii);
                me.add(jsonObject2.getString("nomco"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        listcom.addAll(me);//pour list view
        listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();        }
}
}
```

this is the error i get " java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

my manifest file

```
  package="com.custmersd.test">
<uses_permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses_permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Ididn't find why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Please update your question with the android manifest . I'm guessing that one of your permissions is inside the application tag.

Comment: Downvoted because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php